# Regexp substr until underscore + digit

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the this string: 'STRING_EXA2MP_3LE'. I want to obtain all the characters until there is an underscore followed by a digit, which in this case would output 'STRING_EXA2MP'. How could I obtain this?

This is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT
    regexp_substr('STRING_EXA2MP_3LE', '[^(_0-9]+', 1, 1)
FROM
    dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Select regexp_replace('STRING_EXA2MP_3LE', '_[0-9].*') from dual

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
SELECT regexp_substr('STRING_EXA2MP_3LE', '(.+)_[0-9]+', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM dual
```

The subexpression in parentheses (`(.+)`), which is subexpression #1 (important later) says "Match 1 or more of any character". The rest of the expression (`_[0-9]+`) says "Match an underscore followed by one or more numeric digits". The last argument to REGEXP_SUBSTR says "Return the value of subexpression #1". So using the subexpression here is important as it allows you to extract a portion of the matched string.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20c4184c610dae527bb5bd3abeabd67b)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('STRING_EXA2MP_3LE', '(.+_?)_[0-9]?', 1, 1,'i',1)
FROM dual;
```